# Mutli-Class Text Classifcation (using TFIDF and SVM). How to implement a scenario where one feedback may belong to more than one class?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification, tfidfvectorizer

I have a file of raw feedbacks that needs to be labeled(categorized) and then work as the training input for SVM Classifier(or any classifier for that matter).

But the catch is, I'm not assigning whole feedback to a certain category. **One feedback may belong to more than one category** based on the topics it talks about (noun n-grams are extracted). So, **I'm labeling the topics(terms) not the feedbacks(documents)**. And so, I've extracted the n-grams using TFIDF while saving their features so i could train my model on. The problem with that is, using tfidf, it returns a document-term matrix that's train_x, but on the other side, I've got train_y; The labels that are assigned to each n-gram (not the whole document). So, I've ended up with a document to frequency matrix that contains x number of rows(no of documents) against a label of y number of n-grams(no of unique topics extracted).

Below is a sample of what the data look like. Blue is the n-grams(extracted by TFIDF) while the red is the labels/categories (calculated for each n-gram with a function I've manually made).

[image]

Instead of putting code, this is my strategy in implementing my concept:

[image]

**The problem** lies in that part where TFIDF produces`x_train = tf.Transform(feedbacks)`, which is a document-term matrix and it doesn't make sense for it to be an input for the classifier against `y_train`, which is the labels for the terms and not the documents. I've tried to transpose the matrix, it gave me an error. I've tried to input 1-D array that holds only feature values for the terms directly, which also gave me an error because the classifier expects from X to be in a `(sample, feature)` format. I'm using Sklearn's version of SVM and TfidfVectorizer.

Simply, I want to be able to use SVM classifier on a list of terms (n-grams) against a list of labels to train the model and then test new data (after cleaning and extracting its n-grams) for SVM to predict its labels.

The solution might be a very technical thing like using another classifier that expects a different format or not using TFIDF since it's document focused (referenced) or even broader, a whole change of approach and concept (if it's wrong).

I'd very much appreciate it if someone could help.